# When launching, nvidia-settings it just hangs

Tags: 11.10, command-line, upgrade, nvidia

I've just upgraded to 11.10 and now nvidia-settings won't launch.  If I run it from the command line (as me or as root) it just hangs.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to completely remove your nvidia drivers from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

You should be greeted with lightdm, this will default everything x the same way a fresh install would. After that you can try installing nvidia from the "Additional Drivers" application.

Comment: nvidia-current-modaliases isn't available.  Does that exist for 11.10?

Comment: Ignore it, it is necessary to id your card only but drivers work without it.

Comment: This didn't work. Still hangs.

Comment: Remove your nvidia-current nvidia-settings packages and reboot, do you get to see the login screen?

Comment: As an option you can do the same solution and use `apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings` to remove any configuration file left over.

Comment: Edited response to instruct on how to reset you xorg completely. after that you can see if reinstalling the driver works for you. leave a comment if it does.

Comment: good it helped. regards