# 11.04 -> 11.10 update problems (Power, Display, Resolution)

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, power-management, updates, suspend

I have serious issues with Ubuntu (64 bit) after upgrading system from 11.04 to 11.10.
My hardware: Asus G53SW (i7-2630QM, 8GB RAM, GF GTX460M)

1. Power (UPower) - when I change behaviour of lid open/close looks like my settings doesn't work at all. Changed closed lid to do nothing and still my notebook suspends when i close the lid,
2. Resolution - system hangs when I try to change resolution. Something weird happens and screen (just before hangs) looks like having a shifted position (like absolute with shift),
3. Display - when I attach external display (with adaptor ring, DVI -> HDMI) and trying to turn it on as separate screen / twin view system hangs on with similiar effects as stated in 2nd point.

Everything worked well on Ubuntu 11.04, so it's 11.10 issue for sure.

Bonus question: how can I change behaviour of special keys like keyboard backlight? acpi_listen doesn't list them, I read that it's something with WMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist question can be answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown/66731#66731)

Other display related question could be better troubleshooted if you did a [reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66193/when-launching-nvidia-settings-it-just-hangs/66222#66222) on your nvidia drivers and started a new configuration.

Comment: Looks like solution to the 1st question (+reboot) solved this issue. Reinstallation of drivers helped as well (now it only hungs for some time, but seems to work). Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, I don't have any problems with my nvidia so if there is any information you can add or any suggestions please feel free to do so! ;)

Comment: By the way, have you updated Ubuntu or had a clean installation of the newest version?

Comment: I havent yet, thats why I dont have any problems with it.